# Is it possible to remote control NAO robot with a device such as a Myo Armband?

Tags: python, bluetooth, nao-robot, myo

I am researching whether it is possible to control a NAO with a Myo Armband. I know both devices have bluetooth connects, but my question is whether certain movements in the Myo armband can be programmed with Python. Perhaps install a Python program in a computer command, so the Myo can directly control the NAO.

Has anyone attempted this or would know steps I can take to see whether this is even feasible?

The NAO can be connected via bluetooth to phones and computers and be remotely controlled that way. I've written simple movement Python code that can make the NAO move forward and backward. I'm not sure what to do next to try and take this a step further.

In Choreographe, which is the program used to control the NAO, empty script boxes still have to be opened and programmed to upload the behavior to the NAO, which is why I'm unsure how this could even be bypassed with the Myo.

I just want to see if it is possible to somehow do simple behaviors with the Myo.

Comment: Show us how far have you progessed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can write some sort of a bluetooth middleware to translate commands between the Myo and the NAO. That being said, I personally had better luck using the Kai (vicara.co) rather than the Myo. But hey, that's up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. NAO v6 has integrated bluetooth, and for previous versions of NAO you could plug a bluetooth dongle in the head.

As for how to integrate it in NAO: I often use [the robot-jumpstarter tempaltes](https://github.com/aldebaran/robot-jumpstarter), for example "pythonapp" is basically a standalone Python script wrapped in a Choregraphe package (but you can program it as if it was a python script - split your code into modules, include thrid-party libraries, etc.). Combine with the [Python MYO MSDK](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/myo-python), and you should be able to build something.

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjoH6bTm9hI) for a video of NAO + MYO + Occulus Rift.